# Remove String from Array in Parse User Android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to remove a string from an array of strings in Parse. I have an array in my Parse User class and I want to remove a specific value from it. Even when iterating through the array and getting the exact value that I want to remove, it doesn't remove it after saving. I can't seem to even get the code below to work. Is there something silly I'm missing? I can add values to the array without any issues whatsoever.

```
    public void removeBtn(View view) {


    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("friendAccept").remove(0);
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();


}
```

Comment: The remove all function doesn't work either. I can get the array to remove the item and the adapter updates as if the item was deleted but Parse never saves the new array so upon logging out of the program the list is back to normal.

Comment: You have to "put" the new array back onto the user before you save the user.  I'll post an answer below.

Comment: Justin, still have issues with this?  Give me answer a look, it explains the mistake you're making

Answer (score 0):

Try using a callback to see if it's really doing something while saving in background:

```
 ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saved in background");
                if (e == null)
                    //ok
                else
                    //something else went wrong
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Callback returns a mere "Successful". That's what was odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I think this due to you have not use put method.

```
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    List<Object> list = user.getList("friendAccept");
    if(list.size()>0) {
        list.remove(0);
    }
    user.put("friendAccept", list);
    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "saved in background");
            if (e == null)
                //ok
            else
                //something else went wrong
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed to put your modified array back into the ParseUser.

```
public void removeBtn(View view) {

ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) currentUser.getList("friendAccept");
myList.remove(0);
currentUser.put("friendAccept", myList);
currentUser.saveInBackground();


}
```